# Potential near a strip - conformal maps

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, conductors

I need to solve this problem:

> An infinitly long wire(at $y=h,x=0$) placed (symmetrically) next to a semi-infinite conducting strip ($y<0$ and $|x|<a/2$). Find the potential in all space.

The hint of the exercise is to use conformal maps.

My idea: First used the map $f(z) = z*i$ to rotate the strip, then used $g(z) = e^{\pi z/a}$ to map it to a $Re(z)>0, |z|>1$ and then using $h(z) = z^{-2}$ to map that to a cirlce. Afterwards mapping the circle to an upper half plane(by sending -i to 0, 0 to i and i to inf). After that I've used the method of image charges(in this case wires) to find the potential in that new simple geometry.

The problem is that my solution is periodic(which it shouldnt) since I've used the exponetial function. Any hitns on how I could avoid that? I haven't found a way to map it to a half plane without exponetial functions.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.